# search bar textbox overlay on all fragments

Tags: android, search, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

I have a tab swipe application like this

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
 ActionBar.TabListener
 {



 }
```

I have several fragments in the app and I use the actionbar tabs to go between them. How can I (as well as the tabs) have a searchbar that is constantly overlayed no matter what fragment I'm in like how the actionbar is always there on every fragment tab.
I was reading up on the merge keyword, is it possible to make a xml file with just a textbar and then just merge that with all the fragment views? or is there a better way, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the merge element. You can just put your searchbar view in your activity layout, above your ViewPager.